# Can you fight May/Brendan again after Delta Episode?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Can you fight May again? Because I really want to fight her again.

Answer (score 2):

You can battle May/Brendan once after the credits, on [Route 103](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hoenn_Route_103#Pok.C3.A9mon_Omega_Ruby_and_Alpha_Sapphire). Once you have defeated your rival, however, you cannot battle her/him again.

Source, [PokemonDB](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/225835/can-i-battle-may-again-in-oras)